# SQL query get record table A based on parentid Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

[SOLVED: thanks to bluefeet and Brian I got to build this working query (turned out I also needed a fourth table / view)]"

```
SELECT        A.SalesLineID, A.ArticleResultID, B.ID, C.ID, D.Value
FROM            VIEWA AS A 
                INNER JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.ArticleResultID = B.ArticleResultID 
                AND B.Name = N'Collect' AND DAPR.Value = 1 
                INNER JOIN TABLEC AS C ON B.ArticleResultID = C.ID 
                AND C.Name='Assemble' 
                AND C.Value = 1 
                INNER JOIN TABLED AS D ON D.ArticleResultID = C.ParentId 
                AND D.Name = 'IndexY'
WHERE        (A.SalesID = @SalesID)
```

[UPDATE: I've made a mistake assuming IndexY/Color and ProdId where fields Table A is some kind of parameter / property table with only 5 columns ID - NAME - VALUE - ARTICLERESULTID - PRODID. IndexY is a value of the Name field..]

I'm having trouble building the right sql query to get this trick done:

I have the following 2 tables:

```
Table A 
ID Name         Value   ArticleResultID     ProdID    Color
1  Operation    Collect             110         10    BLACK
2  IndexY            10             110         10    - 
3  Operation    Collect             101         11    WHITE


Table B
ID  ParentID    Name        Value       
101 110     Assemble        1       
101 100     Assemble        0
```

Steps:

```
Find record in A with Name = Operation and Value = Collect and ProdId = 11 AS ORG_A
Find record in B With B.ID = ORG_A.ArticleResultId AND B.NAME = 'Assemble'AND B.VALUE = 1 AS B
Find record in A With A.ArticleResultID = B.ParentID as NEW_A
```

In the above scenario thats ORG_A.ArticleResultID = 11 --> B.ParentID = 110 --> NEW_A.ARTICLERESULTID = 110 --> (IndexY - Value - 10)

Much appreciated if someone can tell me how to build this query..

Best regards,

Mike D

[OLD DESCRIPTION:]

I'm having trouble building the right sql query to get this trick done:

I have the following 2 tables:

```
Table A 
Name        Value   ArticleResultID      IndexY      Color  ProdID
Operation   Collect             110         10           -       0
Operation   Collect             101         _        Black     100  


Table B
ID  ParentID    Name        Value   Dx      Dy
101 110     Assemble        1       1000    500 
101 100     Assemble        0       400     300
```

I want to fetch all records from A where NAME equals 'operation', VALUE equals 'Collect' and PRODID = '100' but I also want (here's my problem) the IndexY value of the record in Table A with the PARENTID in Table B which joins on TABLE B.ID = A.ArticleResultID AND Name = 'Assemble' and VALUE = '1'

In the above scenario thats ParentID 110 which gives me the record in Table A with ArticleResultID 110 with IndexY (10).

Much appreciated if someone can tell me how to build this query..

Best regards,

Mike D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your requirements are not the clearest. How about this:

```
SELECT a1.*, a2.indexy as additionalIndexY
FROM ta a1
INNER JOIN tb b
    ON a1.articleresultid = b.id
INNER JOIN ta a2
    ON b.parentid = a2.articleresultid
WHERE a1.name = 'Operation'
    AND a1.prodid = 100
    AND b.name = 'Assemble'
    AND b.value = 1
```

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef643/5) with a working version

If you just want the record with the 110 articleresultid, then:

```
SELECT a2.*
FROM ta a1
INNER JOIN tb b
    ON a1.articleresultid = b.id
INNER JOIN join ta a2
    ON b.parentid = a2.articleresultid
WHERE a1.name = 'Operation'
    AND a1.prodid = 100
    AND b.name = 'Assemble'
    AND b.value = 1
```

see the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef643/6) for the second example

Comment: Thnx bluefeet, I made a mistake describing the problem however. Hope my update's a bit clearer...

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT a.*,c.IndexY
  FROM [TableA] a
  JOIN [TableB] b ON a.ArticleResultId = b.id
                 AND b.Name ='Assemble'
                 AND b.Value = 1
  JOIN [TableA] c ON b.ParentId = c.ArticleResultID
  WHERE a.name = 'Operation'
    AND a.Value = 'Collect'
    AND a.ProdId = 100
```